# Rounded corners for Flex Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex3, flash

I want to keep `DataGrid` and `AdvancedDataGrid` corners round by some px amount, like other components.

What is the proper way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to create a custom skin for your datagrid, enclose the datagrid within a rectangle, and apply a corner radius to the rectangle:

```
<s:Rect left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" radiusX="3" radiusY="3">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="#ccff99" alpha=".8"/>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```